# query is working in workbench but not in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

the Java code

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value ="select account_id , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS location_id from locations ll where ll.parent_location in (SELECT id as building_id FROM locations l WHERE l.id IN (SELECT location_id as building_id FROM location_feature lf WHERE lf.feature_id = :featureId)) group by account_id")
List<Location> findByFeatureId(@Param("featureId") Integer featureId);
```

getting an error

```js
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "could not execute query; SQL [select account_id , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS location_id from locations ll where ll.parent_location in (SELECT id as building_id FROM locations l WHERE l.id IN (SELECT location_id as building_id FROM location_feature lf WHERE lf.feature_id = ?)) group by account_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query"
}
```

Comment: @Query("select account_id , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id SEPARATOR ',') AS location_id from locations ll where ll.parent_location in (SELECT id as building_id FROM locations l WHERE l.id IN (SELECT location_id as building_id FROM location_feature lf WHERE lf.feature_id = :featureId)) group by account_id")
 List<Location> findByFeatureId(@Param("featureId") Integer featureId);

Comment: try above without nativeQuery=true

Comment: Without the full stacktrace it is impossible to help you.